# Is it Good practice to use iFrame in ionic v2+?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I don't have intention to use iFrame in my Ionic App code base. But due to the Usability and requirements cases i started using it.

Well, this is our scenario:

We will be receiving dynamic contents from the external Urls, the Urls will be dynamic. After loading the external URL content in iFrame, We will be sending the content as an email from our Ionic App custom email functionality.

***Current Approach - Sample:***

```
<div style="overflow:auto;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch">
    <iframe style="width:100%;height:600px" src="www.mydynamicurl.com"></iframe>
</div>
```

We were able to achieve pretty much what we want.

But question is, Generally is it good approach to use iFrame with external Url loaing inside ionic app?

Is there any other way to use in Ionic2?

Please suggest..